# How do I unfreeze my iPod Nano 4th Gen?

Tags: startup, performance, ipod-nano

**tl;dr** -- My iPod hangs on the boot screen (black background, silver apple logo). When I try to restore it (on both my Virtual Windows XP and on a Mac laptop), it'll restore fine, but when it reboots the iPod, the iPod'll hang on the apple logo screen, just like before.

---

**Update:** I've booted a Windows XP virtualbox, and have the latest iTunes running on it. Whenever I tell iTunes to restore it (while my iPod is in disk mode, since that's the only way it is recognized), it'll download the software, restore my iPod, then say that the iPod is rebooting and that I need to make sure it stays connected.

However, once it boots, it still hangs on the apple logo, and isn't recognized by the computer (host or guest). If I boot it into disk mode, it is recognized, and iTunes shows the "Welcome to your new iPod" screen; the iPod is wiped, and presumably installed the new software.

---

I've searched and searched for an answer, and although I've found numerous posts on other sites similar to my problem, most of them haven't worked for me.

Basically, what's happened is about half a year ago, my iPod would occasionally freeze, and I could solve the issue by restarting it (<kbd>Menu</kbd>+<kbd>Select</kbd>); about late November last year, however, my iPod froze on the boot screen (black screen with apple logo), and since then I haven't been able to do anything - it just hangs on that screen until it completely drains the battery. My problem is similar to the one in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD63iG8qMpE).

---

Is there a way I can fix my iPod Nano 4th Gen?

Also, I'd prefer if I could do it without iTunes, since I'm running Ubuntu and Wine has spotty iTunes support, but I *can* run a VirtualBox of Windows if need be.

Comment: Since links change, and break, it's usually a good idea just to describe your problem as best you can. Being concise always helps to get answers.

Comment: have you tried dfu mode?

Comment: by the way, you could try useing redsnow to kick it out of loop boot...

Comment: @Zo219 I did describe the issue (hangs on boot screen) in the second paragraph, the link was merely for extra description. What I should have also added originally (which I will now) is that the computer doesn't detect it either; the iPod receives power, but I can't find any indicators it's being recognized anywhere on the computer.

Comment: @Macmaniman I'm looking into dfu mode and redsn0w right now, but I think the issue I'm going to have with those is that the computer doesn't recognize that it's been plugged in.

Comment: hm, yes you did mention that you use linux, however DFU mode should be recognised by itunes, on Win and Mac, i cant speak for linux! my sugestion is try to get a hold of a mac, and try dfu and itunes restore. personaly ive assisted atleast 50+ persons with their problems and many of them seemed imposible to fix, but ive yet failed on any softare problem, my point is dont give up, unless you know its HW! i assume uve tried different usb ports and what not? oh by the way,before you use the wannabe DFU or Disk mode, try switching your hold button to on and off before!

Comment: one last point, above you mention menu + reset shurly you mean menue and select right?that is. Hold switch on then off, then menue + center button right?

Comment: @Macmaniman Ah, yes, my mistake, thanks for catching that; I've now fixed it above. I downloaded redsn0w, but I think it's for iPhones, iPod Touches, and iPads, so that won't work. I have tried different ports, and on the weekend I'm going to either set up a windows virtual machine and use iTunes through that, or try and get my hands on a friend's mac. I'll let you know what happens with that.

Comment: do that, and yes you are right, forget about redsn0w but give the " 
one last point, above you mention menu + reset surly you mean menue and select right?that is. Hold switch on then off, then menue + center button right? " a good try, diffrent usb ports and what not, cuz as i said, ive yet to lose an iPod because of software

Comment: So I misread the directions for booting into disk mode, and I foolishly tried pressing the buttons *after* the apple logo appeared; so I can (and have) boot into diagnostic and disk mode.  Likewise, I have a windows virtualbox running, with iTunes installed and running wonderfully. I'm copying my music off my iPod now, and I'll let you know how it goes, and what I do.

Comment: Did everyone catch that this is an iPod nano? There is no such thing as DFU mode on an iPod nano. Likewise, there is no Redsnow. These are iOS-based tricks. From having worked for years at an Apple Store and troubleshot every generation iPod nano from the 1st gen to the latest, I would suggest it's time to replace the unit or take it in for repair at the Genius Bar.

Comment: I updated the "tl;dr" section with the latest info: I've tried restoring with both my Windows XP virtualbox and a Mac laptop, and although it'll restore fine, when it reboots the iPod to finish the restoration process, the iPod'll hang on the apple logo screen, just like before.

Answer (score 1):

For restoring, iTunes is the best option. Once you’ve determined if iTunes can restore the device - if not, you should have a specific error code from iTunes that explains precisely what’s not working (or have an error code to report here).

If iTunes can’t restore the device, a hardware repair may be in order as well.